# How to get next XML Element value?

Tags: c#, asp.net, xml, linq, xml-parsing

```
XDocument coordinates = XDocument.Load("http://feeds.feedburner.com/TechCrunch");
System.IO.StreamWriter StreamWriter1 = new System.IO.StreamWriter(DestFilePath);

foreach (var coordinate in coordinates.Descendants("guid"))
                {
                    string Links = coordinate.Value;                 
                    StreamWriter1.WriteLine(Links + Environment.NewLine );
                }

StreamWriter1.Close();
```

Using this code for the above URL (http://feeds.feedburner.com/TechCrunch) i am able to obtain all the links but i also want to obtain <**description**> and <**content:encoded**> element values.

The problem is that i want to obtain <**description**> etc values along with their **guid** values so that i can store them in serially (in database).

Should i use **LINQ** of something for this purpose ?
But how please tell ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should iterate over each "item" and retrieve its properties. Do not forget about the "content" namespace.

```
  XNamespace nsContent = "http://purl.org/rss/1.0/modules/content/";
  XDocument coordinates = XDocument.Load("http://feeds.feedburner.com/TechCrunch");

  foreach (var item in coordinates.Descendants("item"))
  {
          string link = item.Element("guid").Value;
          string description = item.Element("description").Value;
          string content = item.Element(nsContent + "encoded").Value;

  }
```

Comment: its showing error "Object reference not set to an instance of an object."

Comment: by the time I had written all my code, you posted the same basic thing.  =)

Comment: by the way which one it is ? System.Xml.Linq.XDocument technique or  System.Xml.XmlDocument ? just want to know as i don't have any idea

Comment: @MegaHerz : One more thing... its Content string fetches all the data of the element but what to do if i am interested in only data between <p>..</p> i.e text data only...No links no images ?

Answer (score 0):

One way is you can try enumerating them individualy,

```
foreach (var coordinate in coordinates.Descendants())
    {
    foreach (var element in coordinate.Elements("description"))
    {
            string Links = element.Value;                 
            StreamWriter1.WriteLine(Links + Environment.NewLine );
    }
            foreach (var element in coordinate.Elements("guid"))
    {
            string Links = element.Value;                 
            StreamWriter1.WriteLine(Links + Environment.NewLine );
    }   
    //.................         
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Not sure but try .DescendantsAndSelf()

Answer (score 0):

I suggest that you use XPATh to iterate over each //content/item and then get that item's guid, content, etc.

```
using System;
using System.Net;
using System.Xml;

namespace TechCrunch
{
  class Program
  {
    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
      Console.WriteLine("Hello World!");

      try
      {
        HttpWebRequest request = HttpWebRequest.CreateHttp(
          "http://feeds.feedburner.com/TechCrunch");
        WebResponse response = request.GetResponse();

        XmlDocument feedXml = new XmlDocument();
        feedXml.Load(response.GetResponseStream());

        XmlNodeList itemList = feedXml.SelectNodes("//channel/item");
        Console.WriteLine("Found " + itemList.Count + " items.");

        foreach(XmlNode item in itemList)
        {
          foreach(XmlNode child in item.ChildNodes)
          {
            Console.WriteLine("There is a child named " + child.Name);
          }
        }
      }
      catch(Exception ex)
      {
        Console.WriteLine(ex.ToString());
      }

      Console.Write("Press any key to continue . . . ");
      Console.ReadKey(true);
    }
  }
}
```